# Text doesn't have same size on different emulators

Tags: android, android-studio, button, text, size

**Emulator 1:**

[image: Emulator 1]

**Emulator 2**

[image: Emulator 2]

How can I keep the same text size on button on different emulator?
I am using these lines of code to set a relative size that keeps the ratio, but when I run the program on 2 different emulators (real emulators) the text gets crazy sizes

> Code Snippets

```
    btn_play_game1.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            btn_play_game1.setTextSize((float) (btn_play_game1.getHeight() * btn_play_game1.getWidth() * 0.00013));
        }
    });
```

Also I am using LinearLayout in my `xml` files, If that matters.

Answer (score 2):

You're calling [`setTextSize(float)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextSize(float)):

> Set the default text size to the given value, interpreted as "scaled pixel" units. **This size is adjusted based on the current density and user font size preference**.

Assuming both emulators are set to the same system font size (which will also make the text bigger or smaller) the issue is that you're already providing a final scaled size, by taking the button's dimensions in pixels. But that method is expecting a size in `sp`, a density-independent size that will be scaled according to the device's screen density *and* the user's font preferences. So the higher the screen resolution, the more it's getting scaled up

Here's three options:

- you can use this method and work out the correct `sp` value to use (depending on how big the text should look, try 24 and go from there) - again this will be bigger or smaller depending on the user's prefs
- use the [setTextSize(int, float)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView#setTextSize(int,%20float)) method and pass `TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX` for the first parameter, and your calculated-from-the-pixels size as the second. That way the text size will always be proportional to your button size the way you're calculating it, and the user's font size prefs don't come into it. You'll have to change that `0.00013` value because that's just what happened to work when you were passing a `sp` value
- OR just define the text size in your XML, if you can (e.g. if the Button is a fixed size). Use a `dp` value instead of `sp` if you want it to take up a fixed amount of space (no user scaling) - some text doesn't need to scale

Also that's a weird way of calculating a ratio, I think in this situation you'd generally just take a fraction of the height for consistency, or do something with `minOf(height, width)` if the width is variable - but then you're getting into the complexity of measuring the text to see what it needs to fit, and it's way easier to just let the layout system handle all that. There's a bunch of ways you could do it in XML, but that's another story